# Add extension method to a List and return one

Tags: c#, list, extension-methods

I want to write an extension method for the `List` class that takes a List, sorts the list, and return it back.Extension methods really confuse me.  Can someone help me out with this?

```
public static List<T> sort(this List<T> sortThisList)
{
return MyList//just a test
}
```

For some reason i'm not able to call the extension method

```
List<T> MyList = List<T> tempList;
MyList.sort <<<< doesn't exist.
```

Comment: In the sort method: `return sortThisList;` and then when calling it: `MyList.sort()`

Comment: Start by fixing the *various* compiler errors in all the code you've shown other than the actual method call.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need an extension method for this, there's already a `List.Sort()`. You just seem to want to sort and then return the sorted list, but I'd say that's a bad idea because a fluent interface isn't really appropriate here.

Comment: Also, replace the "T" in `<T>` with an actual type.

Comment: I'm using actual types... it's just pseudo code .... 
This isn't exactly helping lol

Comment: @JiJoeTheMan If it's just pseudocode, then you shouldn't be surprised when it doesn't work properly.  You'll need to take the time to turn your pseudocode into actual C# code if you want to be able to actually run it.

Comment: Your extension method is defined in a static class?

Comment: @Servy Lol ur kidding ?? I used special code in this post, not in my solution ......

Comment: @erikscandola nothing's wrong with that Oo

Comment: @JiJoeTheMan Then you're not showing us the code that you have a problem with, and as such, there's no way for us to know what you did wrong.

Comment: @JiJoeTheMan Exstension methods must be in a static class to works.

Comment: @erikscandola I thought u were saying that it was wrong... but yea,, my fault I should've shown the full code

Comment: Ok, so your extension method is in a static class correct? It's in different namespace than the one where you have to use it? Let me explain: namespace where you are the extension method `ProjectName.Extensions`; namespace where you need to use it `ProjectName.DifferentName`. If it is you need to import extension method by using.

Answer (score 0):

First create a static class:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{

}
```

Then on it add your exstension methods:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static List<T> sort(this List<T> sortThisList)
    {
        // Your code here

        return sortThisList;
    }

    public static void methodWithoutReturn(this List<T> sortThisList)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```